# How to create a new Campaign Tag in Marketing cloud Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a requirement to create a new Campaign Tag in Marketing cloud Exact Target.

please help me on how to create a new campaign tags, i can see the existing ones but i am not able to find out how to create a new tag.

Thanks
Abraham

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on your name on the top right side. Go to Admin.
Then Account, go to Tags. Then on the top right again, you'll see Create Tag button.

There you can create the tags for Campaigns. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much Maneesh .. This is perfectly what i needed.. just a doubt though can this Tags be restricted to business units or created only to specific business units .. thanks in advance

Comment: I think they are created only for specific business units. I haven't seen the option to configure the permissions got tags. If you think I have answered your question, please mark it as correct answer. Thanks !